# Авторские права на аудиодорожки

Tags: android, google-play, youtube, авторские-права

Можно ли использовать фразы людей из YouTube  в своих приложениях, то есть я возьму видео и сделаю из нее аудиодорожку   а ее порежу на фрагменты и при нажатии определенных кнопок в моем приложении будет воспроизводится та или иная аудио дорожка.

Comment: Можешь, но при этом, если ты будешь получать коммерческую выгоду, они могут подать иск. Предложу записать необходимые звуковые файлы самостоятельно и через программы подкрутить эффекты, не будет как оригинал, но и переживать по поводу авторских прав меньше будешь)

Comment: Какой максимальный ущерб они могут сделать со своим иском?

Comment: Зависит от того насколько это раскрученное видео или аудиодорожка(в плане того, кто ее озвучивал) Если ты планируешь получать экономическую выгоду, выложил приложение через тот же Google Play, то думюа скорее всего удалят просто приложение, либо через суд будут решать, там уже судом все решается, в этом плане я не могу ответить точно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая концепция *Fair Use* - или *добросовестное/честное использование*.

Предполагается, что если вы используете контент (в данном случае музыкальный) в "честных целях", то можно использовать без прямого разрешения правообладателя.

**Пример честного использования:**

Допустим вы воспроизводите кусок произведения и потом критикуете, рецензируете его - типа: ударные здесь подкачали, зато верхний "Си" у певца идеален.

**Пример нечестного использования**

Перед своим клипом вы делаете вставку из чужого произведения.

[Fair Use для Youtube здесь](https://www.youtube.com/yt/copyright/fair-use.html)

> при нажатии определенных кнопок в моем приложении будет воспроизводится та или иная аудио дорожка

это не Fair Use - я полагаю :)